# Does the morphism of composition have some universal property?

Tags: ct.category-theory, computer-science, universal-property, cartesian-closed-categories

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three objects in the category Set. For simplicity, assume that their underlying sets contain a finite number of elements, a, b and c respectively. Using the usual Haskell notation for types, there exists exactly $(c^a)^{c^b×b^a}$ morphisms from the object/type ($b\rightarrow c$, $a\rightarrow b$) to the object/type $a\rightarrow c$. Among this potentially huge set of morphisms, exactly one is the (uncurried) composition function, defined as ${\rm compose}\, (g, f) = g\circ f$.

My question is, does this particular morphism have any universal property that make it possible to identify using only category theory?

This is the computer-scientist-toying-with-categories-version of the question. If you prefer a version written by a proper mathematician, please refer to [The universal property of composition of morphisms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315211/the-universal-property-of-composition-of-morphisms)

Comment: I know the Thought Police are going to come along and Close this question. It's very difficult to think of a meaningful positive answer and indeed I've already thought of two situations where there is a choice of ways to compose.  However, I believe that the question should stay here as a philosophical challenge to categorists to find positive answers.

Comment: This question is not uninteresting, not off topic, and not too broad; it is in fact a very interesting one, and I asked something similar quite some time ago: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315211/the-universal-property-of-composition-of-morphisms

Comment: (I *think* my question is $\epsilon$-near to yours; if you have more doubts, feel free to ask)

Comment: @fosco: I decided to post this question because it seemed to me your question and proposed theorem was about something else that I didn't quite understand (I am but a mere computer scientist), but I will try to read it again more carefully, and update my question with a reference to your proposed solution. At a first glance, the main difference is the setting. You assume a 2-Category, but as a computer scientist, most of the time I only have the benefit of working in a category that is cartesian closed (Set). But then again, your theorem should be applicable to monads, I think, and that's good

Comment: Anyways, I'll add a reference to your proposed theorem, and leave it to others to decide if my cartesian closed, non-2-category setting is enough to motivate a separate question. My main defence is that my question has more of a popular-science nature that might attract the attention of computer scientists, but I am unsure if that is an asset or a liability…

Comment: As I'm sure you're aware, the pointwise evaluation map $ev\colon B^A \times A \to B$ has a universal property, but that doesn't quite help here! The trick is to identify what data in the map is variable, and which is fixed. Or, to put it another way, what variable is the map natural in? For $ev$, we fix $A$ and $B$ and let the thing in the $B^A$ slot vary, to consider generic $X\times A\to B$. Then $B^A$ together with $ev$ is the universal thing. What is the analogue for your setup?

Comment: Some richer notion of natural might be needed, of course, such as dinaturality, but I haven't thought too hard about it. One issue is that there is covariant and contravariant behaviour in the middle slot (`b` in your notation)

Comment: @Paul Taylor: I am totally fine with there being many arrows satisfying my condition. In category theory, one can never hope to get more specific than "up to isomorphism", and this goes for arrows with universal properties as well. I am pretty certain there are many arrows in exponential objects in Set that satisfy the same universal property as regular function evaluation. One that consistently permutates input or output for example.

Comment: Thanks @Buzz :)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, as David Roberts pointed out in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395494/does-the-morphism-of-composition-have-some-universal-property#comment1012526_395494) above, the composition map

```
c :: hom a b -> hom b c -> hom a c
c f g = g . f
```

and the evaluation map

```
ev :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
ev f x = f x
```

share a common property, that of forming the components of a *cowedge*. I will now switch to category-theory notation, I'm confident you'll be able to translate back in pseudo-Haskell-ish/generic FP syntax.

Being a cowedge means that

1. fixed objects $a,c$ of your category, the correspondence $(b,b')\mapsto \hom_{\cal A}(a,b)\times\hom_{\cal A}(b',c)$ is a functor ${\cal A}^\text{op}\times {\cal A} \to {\sf Set}$; let's call it $T$
2. the family of maps $c_b : T(b,b)=\hom(a,b)\times\hom(b,c)\to \hom(a,c)$ behaves as follows, once a morphism $f : b\to b'$ is given: the square

   $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
   T(b',b) @>T(f,b)>> T(b,b) \\ 
   @VT(b',f)VV @VVc_bV \\ 
   T(b',b') @>>c_{b'}> \hom(a,c)
   \end{CD}$$
   is commutative. (I'll leave this verification to you).

Not only this; there is a category of cowedges for $T$, i.e. families $\underline g = \{g_b : T(b,b) \to E\}$ pointing to generic sets $E$ and fitting into the same commutative squares. A morphism between a cowedge $\underline g$ and a cowedge $\underline h$ is a map between their codomains, with the property that the obvious diagram commutes (I'll leave it to you to find what is the obvious diagram). Now,

Claim. $\underline c = \{c_b : T(b,b) \to \hom(a,c)\}$ is the initial object in the category of cowedges for $T$ (a functor that, let me remind you, depends on $a,b$!).

I'll leave to you this verification.

*This* is the universal property of the composition maps of a category.

PS: what about the evaluation map $\text{ev} : B^A\times A \to B$? Well, in a cartesian closed category its components also form not only a cowedge (this is true in every monoidal closed category, and in fact it is true for every parametric adjunction, but nevermind); they form an initial one! In a sense, feeding a function with an element in its domain is "the simplest operation one can perform", given a function and an element (of course, this intuition deeply relies on the fact we can resort to elements; in category theory, this is often not possible). Similarly, given two arrows in a category that *can* be composed, composing them is the most natural thing you could do.

Comment: On a first glance, this looks very much like what I am looking for. I'll look into cowedges.

Comment: There's a very long story you can tell about them :D https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503

Comment: To sum this up, we have$$\int^{B} \hom(A,B) \times \hom(B,C) = \hom(A,C).$$In fact, for any set-valued functor $F$ we have $$\int^{B} F(B) \times \hom(B,C) = F(C).$$

Comment: Yes, I wanted to add it myself. :)